# How to know btc wallet name/website ?

Tags: wallet

Is there any way to know bitcoins wallet name using these details

pubkey publicaddress rsz signatures sha-256 ripemd160 script signature ( asm & hex )

Comment: if yes then please tell me how , and I just found a website which can tell the website/wallet name using public address " bitcoinwhoswho " but when I pasted publicaddress on that website it says " Wallet Name : 1237a80b42d675d2 " what does this means ?

Answer (score 1):

None of the values mentioned are linkable in any way to the software that generated the address. Bitcoin Addresses are standardized, and all wallets follow identical rules for generating them.

Your only option to determine which software an address originated from is to have some backup of the wallet file, or some other indicator, such as an email confirmation.

Comment: then what does this means Wallet Name : 1237a80b42d675d2

Comment: That is likely just some internal accounting mechanism used by whichever site gave you that. It has no blockchain-level relation to that address